# FireFox Fullscreen Close On Flash

Tags: flash, firefox, fullscreen

I use this plugin http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/ for fullscreen a flash game. The plugin works very fine in Chrome and IE. 
But Firefox close the fullscreen after click and doubleclick inside the flash game. 
It is possible to disable it?

Comment: Why are you using a plugin to fullscreen your flash game when flash can do the job ?

Comment: its a flash gaming site with many games ;)